# When an object added to a Bundle can no longer be updated?

Tags: android, bundle

I have the following code concerning `Bundles` in `Android`:

```
Bundle bundleFromIntent = getActivity().getIntent().getBundleExtra(Constants.CURRENCY);
bundleFromIntent.putParcelable(Constants.CURRENCY_ITEM, coin);

// convert the value after the refresh if the selected currency is not USD
if (!"USD".equals(savedCurrency.getCode())) {
    coin.setLastPrice(200);
}
```

In the following example Coin initially has the the `lastPrice` value to `100`.
I add that value to the `bundleFromIntent` .

What is strange is that after that addition, if I change the value from `coin` , the value in the `Bundle` also gets modified to `200` instead of `100` which is the value when I've added it to the `Bundle`.

Is this normal ? Why does the value added previously in the `Bundle` also get changed and when is the object added to the Bundle no longer able to be changed.

For the `Coin` object I am using `Parceable`.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java#523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check source code of `Bundle` class you would find the following implementation.

```
/* package */ ArrayMap<String, Object> mMap = null;
...

public void putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value) {
    unparcel();
    mMap.put(key, value);
    mFdsKnown = false;
}
```

This means the object instance you added does not get written into a parcel, but is just stored into a map. Thus, if you modify a property of that instance, value gets changed.

Writing into a parcel happens later, when `Intent` gets sent, which is later in time. All changes you do to the instance will be applied to the instance stored in bundle too, because, in fact, this is the same instance.

> Is this normal?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal ?

Yes.

> Why does the value added previously in the Bundle also get changed

Because it is the same object.

> when is the object added to the Bundle no longer able to be changed.

You can change it whenever you want.

However, certain uses of an `Intent`, such as passing it to `startActivity()`, will result in inter-process communication (IPC). This will involve converting the `Intent` and its extras into a `byte[]` to pass to a core OS process. Even if the activity you are starting up is one of your own, that IPC still occurs, as will the IPC from the core OS process back to yours to have your desired activity start up. That process of converting the `Intent` into a `byte[]` and back into an `Intent` will result in a new `Coin` object being created, as part of creating the new `Intent`.

Not *every* use of `Intent` will have this effect -- notably, `LocalBroadcastManager` "broadcasts" do not make a new `Intent` and a new `Coin`. But if you start an activity, start or bind to a service, or send a broadcast, that involves IPC and will result in a new `Coin` being part of what the activity, service, or receiver gets.